# Codrops Page Transitions. How do I create seperate buttons instead of list items for the effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im currently in a deep learning process for a school project. After a month I perfectly understood the concept of css3 and html, including, but very limited, some basic javascript.
I have read alot of tutorials and have found a new one which includes a demo which is truly fascinating to me. It uses a drop down menu list to trigger the page transition effects. Studying the code it starts to make sense to me. However, im starting to wonder how to to apply seperate individual buttons instead of creating list items as a trigger.

I have no clue where to start or which part of the code has to be changed. I would be happy for some feedback.

The Demo: http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/

Comment: I was wondering the same

Comment: Codrops does not really write the simplest Javascript, some of their scripts are using quite advanced concepts. I would recommend to start with learning from books and sites (Head First JS, CodeAcademy, Codeschool ), then start a project so you can learn while building.

Answer (score 1):

Even i wondered the same. with their code i extracted few classes and created example in fiddle.

For animations code go through their animation.css and use required animation classes. for example i have extracted this class

```
.pt-page-moveFromRight {
            -webkit-animation: moveFromRight .6s ease both;
            animation: moveFromRight .6s ease both;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes moveFromRight {
            from { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
        }
        @keyframes moveFromRight {
            from { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); transform: translateX(100%); }
        }
```

Check out example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zb5nacc8/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this: https://github.com/icodebuster/transition.js plugin 
they use the same code only they are separate buttons that trigger the transitions